# In a manual configuration of Spring Batch, @StepScope is giving 'No Scope registered for scope name' error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am having a batch configuration file on which I cannot use `@EnableBatchProcessing` because it creates some beans on its own (like `transactionManager`) which my application already has and whose names/qualifiers I cannot change.
So, I created below config class it compiles fine. But when the job runs, I get error `org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep, message=Encountered an error executing step transformStep in job consInvoiceJob  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'transformStep'`

```
package com.example.billing.invoice.batch;

import com.example.billing.invoice.util.CallOtherApis;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Spring Batch configuration
 */
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    
    //required beans


    @Bean
    //@StepScope
    @Scope(scopeName = "transformStep", proxyMode = TARGET_CLASS)
    //@Value("#{jobParameters['param1']}") String param1, @Value("#{jobParameters['param2']}}") Integer param2
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<InvDto> reader() {

        String sql = String.format("""
                //my sql which would use job params
                """,

        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<InvDto>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .name("reader")
                .sql(sql)
                .rowMapper(new ConsInvoiceToInvoicesRowMapper())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Job job(Step transformStep, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("job")
                .start(transformStep)
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step transformStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager batchTransactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("transformStep")
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .transactionManager(batchTransactionManager)
                .<InvDto, InvDto>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(new CustomItemProcessor())
                .writer(new CustomWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jobExplorer")
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
        serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        JobExplorerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(routingDataSource);
        factoryBean.setJdbcOperations(jdbcTemplate);
        factoryBean.setSerializer(serializer);
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistry jobRegistry() {
        return new MapJobRegistry();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobOperator jobOperator(JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobRepository jobRepository, JobRegistry jobRegistry, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);

        return jobOperator;
    }


    @Override
    @Bean(name = "jobRepository")
    public JobRepository createJobRepository() {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(routingDataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        try {
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to access job parameters in reader and that is the reason I am using `StepScope`.

Tried creating bean of StepScop like I did for others (which are auto configured when use `@EnableBatchConfiguration`), but not sure how to create instance of `StepScope`.

```
    @Bean
    public StepScope stepScope(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
        stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
        stepScope.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        beanFactory.registerScope(StepScope.SCOPE_NAME, stepScope);
        return stepScope;
    }
```

Went through multiple articles and SO questions but all of them are using `@EnableBatchConfiguration`
Debugging more gives the exact line it is failing:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/b1ac90df68e54b6a6cbd6ae1d832e40b37d8fc0e/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/AbstractStep.java#L226

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Spring Batch yourself, then you need to declare the step scope as a bean in the application context (ie there is no need to register it in the beanFactory as shown in the code you shared).

You can also add/import the [ScopeConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/0a1cdb095f416584dc187bd90ddf4c3c705ae259/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/ScopeConfiguration.java#L30) class in your Spring application context. This is the class imported by `@EnableBatchProcessing`.